# ORA-00917: missing comma when insert not exist in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I have query like this :

```
INSERT INTO KONTAK (IDKONTAK, NAMA, NOHP, ALAMAT, GROUPKONTAK_FK) VALUES 
(SQ_IDKONTAK.NEXTVAL, 'ANDIKA PRATAMA', '+6285226202202', 'JPR', '' WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM KONTAK WHERE NAMA = 'AMIN'))
```

I want insert data to KONTAK table based on the values where not exist in KONTAK NAMA='AMIN'.

When I ran it I got error :

> ORA-00917: missing comma

Any suggestion?

Comment: Ya. It has got problems inserting the 5th column value. Tell me what is the exact value you need in the 5th column?

Comment: Firstly, I don't think that is legal syntax, but besides that, why are you using WHERE EXISTS when you aren't joining to anything?

Comment: I temporarily deleted my answer. Can you better explain what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to do a conditional insert. As in insert a list of constant (harcoded) values only if a certain value doesn't exist already? How does 'AMIN' relate to the values you are inserting?

Comment: @VarunRao when i give value to 5tn column it still missing comma

Comment: @mrjoltcola i will try for suggest below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do a conditional insert, then you can either use MERGE, or use something like this, assuming you want to insert `'ANDIKA PRATAMA'` only if `'AMIN'` is not already there (which doesn't make sense to me, but it seems to be your goal):

```
insert into table1(id1, col1, col2)
  select sequence1.nextval, 'VAL1', 'VAL2'
    from dual
    where not exists (select 1 from table1 where col1 = 'AMIN')
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use `Where` condition in insert with `select` statement;

try;

```
INSERT INTO KONTAK (IDKONTAK, NAMA, NOHP, ALAMAT, GROUPKONTAK_FK) 
select 
SQ_IDKONTAK.NEXTVAL, 'ANDIKA PRATAMA', '+6285226202202', 'JPR', '' 
from dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM KONTAK WHERE NAMA = 'AMIN'
)
```

Comment: you're suggest was true,..but i couldn't vote accept your answer because mrjoltcola was correct answer too,..and he is faster answer than you,... so sorry,....but thanks for the suggest...